# Running server and client in 2 blocks via dispatch queues

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to write an App, that can run two different "threads", one for a Server one for a Client. I have heard, that in Objective-C Dispatch Queues and Blocks are the way to go. I have read the Apple Documentation about Blocks and Dispatch Queues to quite a large extend, however I still fail at the very beginning of my coding.

Am I right, that I need to create 2 Blocks, one for my server code and one for my client code and then put those blocks in the dispatch queue to run concurrently?

I was now trying to create a block for my server, and failed miserably. I tried the following:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Server : NSObject {
    void (^server)(NSString*, int);
}

@end
```

And then

```
 #import "Server.h"

@implementation Server
   server = ^(NSString* host, int port) {
};

@end
```

I thought I would have to declare the block variable first in a header file, so that I can later refer to it in my ViewController. Any answers about the general structure with some code examples would be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise creating a `typedef`, so you can easily create blocks of that type. Like this:

```
typedef void (^ServerBlock)(NSString *host, int port);
```

On your .h:

```
ServerBlock myServerBlock;
```

On your .m:

```
myServerBlock = ^(NSString* host, int port) {};
```

You can put your `typedef` inside a .h file called constants and then import it on your .pch file (this is just suggestion...)

Comment: hi, thanks! However, if I create a Constants.h in my project folder and add #import<Constants.h> after the #ifdec __OBJ __ statement in the .pch file, Xcode can't find my header file?

Comment: If should be able to find. Clean your project, close your project, and restart Xcode.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not. If I add it in "", in my ViewController.h, it finds it. Then however I get the next problem, telling me at the typedef definition "Type name does not allow storage class to be specified".

Comment: I just tested in my project and the solution I provided you, works. If you need further assistance, show me your code.

Comment: Constants.h:
   `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

   @interface Constants : NSObject
   {
        typedef void (^ServerBlock) (NSString *host, int port);
   }
   @end`
Project-Prefix.pch:
   `#import <Availability.h>

   #ifndef __IPHONE_4_0
   #warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK     4.0 and later."
   #endif

   #ifdef __OBJC__
       #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
       #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
       #import <Constants.h>
    #endif`
Server.h:
`#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

  @interface Server : NSObject
  ServerBlock myServer;
@end`

Comment: this `typedef void (^ServerBlock) (NSString *host, int port);` should be inside of Constant.h file... Not a class called SNPTConstants.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19530/discussion-between-user1809923-and-jacky-boy)